# Eclipse Package Explorer CTRL-C and drop in own view with CTRL-V?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, copy-paste, package-explorer

I would like to perform a paste operation on my own view to add some class files which have been selected and copied to the clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the Eclipse package explorer.

My (most likely naive) attempt was to add a drop listener to my view, unfortunately nothing happens if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> with focus on my view. 
I am quite new to GUIs, SWT and Eclipse, maybe I am missing something very essential...

How can I get access to the package explorers clipboard? Or how can I make the stuff in the clipboard being "dropped" to my view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [Handler](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_handlers.html) extension for command `org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste` (check out [Platform Command Framework](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) for more info):

```
  <handler
        class="com.example.PasteHandler"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste">
     <activeWhen>
        <with variable="activePartId">
           <equals value="com.example.MyView"></equals>
        </with>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
```

You can access system clipboard using [`Clipboard`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/Clipboard.html) class. The contents of the clipboard may be of different types, so you need to check whether the type that you're expecting is supported at the given time. Subclasses of [`ByteArrayTransfer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/ByteArrayTransfer.html) are used to convert clipboard contents to suitable Java objects. In your case, I guess the best option is to use [`ResourceTransfer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ResourceTransfer.html) and create Java elements using [JavaCore](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html):

```
Clipboard cb = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());
ResourceTransfer ft = ResourceTransfer.getInstance();
IResource[] classFiles = (IResource[]) cb.getContents(ft);
if (classFiles != null)
    for (IResource file : classFiles) {
        IJavaElement je = JavaCore.create(file);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added an ui.edit.paste handler and a key-binding for CTRL-V. The execution-method of my "paste" handler-class gets executed, but I still could not determine where I can access the the clipboard of the package explorer?

Comment: @user1091534 Eclipse commands use system clipboard. I updated my answer to show how to use it.

Comment: Thanks it basically works now. I am interested in the .java-files and the methods/types/variables that are shown in the package explorer.
I am unsure what is happening, but if I try to select 2 java files with all their methods, types etc. I only receive one of these in the clipboard (the first selected one).
Is there some kind of separation or means for iteration? The data must be somewhere and if selected and copied one-by-one it works.
I am using a JavaElementTransfer for accessing the clipboard-content that should not the reason why only one of my selections is available?

Comment: Not sure what goes wrong for you there. I tested the JavaElementTransfer and multi-selection works fine. Btw, you shouldn't really be using internal classes.

Comment: Hm thats strange:/. Is there an alternative for accessing the JavaElement-Types? Since Eclipse places them there in the JavaElementTransfer-Type why not use them?

Comment: @user1091534 So, as it appears that you can't actually copy types/methods/etc. from Package Explorer, but only classes/files, then my updated solution is enough.